# How to add a SQLite database in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlite, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, github-actions

I have created a flask application that uses a sqlite database in local system. It works fine.

I wanted to deploy this application on AWS on Elastic Beanstalk service. The application is deployed successfully using GitHub actions and Elastic Beanstalk. However, when I try to access the database, it shows Internal Server Error.

I know that to locally create the database, we need to run the following 3 commands -

1. flask db init
2. flask db migrate -m "Message"
3. flask db upgrade

But where should I mention and run these commands in Elastic BeanStalk? Should I mention them in the main.yml file?

Comment: Did you try any Elastic BeanStalk action on the marketplace?
https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=Elastic+Beanstalk

Comment: @GuiFalourd I have already done this while creating the pipeline using GitHub Actions. And it is running. But the real problem is deploying the local SQLite database in EC2.